# Change background image periodically from website in Phonegap Iphone app

Tags: iphone, cordova

I'm new to iPhone development and making an app using PhoneGap framework .

In home screen I have used grid with iPhone style icons to make it like sprigboard layout and there is an background image to this homescreen body tag.

What I want to do is this background image should change periodically (once a week or once a month), after the time interval the app should fetch new image from website may be from the same url, and store in local storage somewhere, so until the next interval the app should show this image as homescreen background. I can use JSON to fetch image.

I don't want to use any native IOS features.

How can I do that using PhoneGap?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to store the image using the local file storage system. Check out 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

You can download the file and store the file name in Localstorage -

Write a javascript function that checks if the name of the file is stored, if so then set the background image using Jquery or the like.

Maybe have a look at this 
http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/1/19/Downloading-files-to-a-PhoneGap-application--Part-1

I ended up saving a dummy file first so I could get the full path to the URL of the folder the file will be stored in (different from each install of the application)